# ¿Evento para saber cuando la vista en Vue3 ha cargado sus elementos?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue3

Lo que estoy intentando implementar es un PRELOADER, quiero que se ejecute al cambiar de vista en vista, esto por si el usuario tiene mala conexión; he creado un componente que contiene mi preloader el cual quiero que se ejecute al navegar en las diferentes vistas de mi aplicación.
He intentado capturar el evento de esta manera en mi componente.

```
<template>
<div class="contenedor" v-show="!isloaded">
    <div v-bind:style="styles" class="spinner spinner--stretch">
      <div v-bind:style="rectStyles" class="rect rect-1"></div>
      <div v-bind:style="rectStyles" class="rect rect-2"></div>
      <div v-bind:style="rectStyles" class="rect rect-3"></div>
      <div v-bind:style="rectStyles" class="rect rect-4"></div>
      <div v-bind:style="rectStyles" class="rect rect-5"></div>
    </div>
</div>
  
</template>

<script>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
export default {
  setup(){
    const isloaded = ref(false);
    onMounted(() => {
      document.onreadystatechange = () =>{
        if(document.readyState == "complete"){
          isloaded.value = true;
          console.log(isloaded.value)
        }
      }
    });
    return{
      isloaded
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Este componente lo uso en cada una de mis vistas y funciona, pero solo cuando recargo la página.
Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda o ejemplos que me puedan compartir, gracias desde ya :)